# Resolution of the image in the top left of a window in Tkinter?

Tags: python, image, tkinter, resolution

What's the appropriate resolution of the image in the top left corner of the Tkinter output window? Because as you can see in the photo, the picture of the clock is sharp and detailed, but when I put it in the corner (with the red arrow), the image loses a lot of quality; I can barely understand it's a clock. So, what's the right resolution? The original resolution of the clock is 256x256. Eventually, is there a way to remove the default feather icon and simply put no image in that space?

[image]

Comment: Of course, if a 256x256 image is scaled down to 16x16, then you are losing a lot of detail and fine lines in the full size images are lost due to the scaling. At that point, it doesn’t matter how “sharp” the original image was. Usually, scaled down application icons will always look bad which is why there are usually multiple sizes designed individually. The .ico file format, which is commonly used for these images, supports specifying multiple sizes.

Comment: Ok thanks now i understand butter, but i need to put the image in the .png format, so even if i convert it in the .ico solving the resolution problem the format isn't a png, how can i do ?

Comment: You should be able to use `tk.iconbitmap()` with an .ico file if you want the full flexibility of the operating system choosing the best size. But if you want to specify a single file size, that’s also ok. For your case, you would need a 16x16 image though.