# How Can I Increase The Resolution Of My Icon In My GUI Window?

Tags: python, tkinter, resolution

I have been doing lots of little tasks in Python to continue learning it and I got to GUIs In python via this code:

```py
from tkinter import * 

count = 0

def click(): 
    global count 
    count += 1
    print("You have clicked the button "+str(count)+" Times")

Window = Tk()

Photo = PhotoImage(file="Pig2.png")

Like_Button = PhotoImage(file="Like-Button2.png")

Window.geometry("600x600")

Window.title("The Ultimate GUI Program")

Icon = PhotoImage(file="AngryBird.png")

Window.iconphoto(True,Icon)

button = Button(Window,
                text="Click me",
                command=click,
                font=("Comic Sans,",10,"bold"),
                fg="Red",
                bg="black",
                activeforeground="Red",
                activebackground="black",
                image=Like_Button,
                compound="bottom") 

button.place(x=50,y=50) 


Window.config(background="white") 

Label = Label(Window, 
              text="You are using the best program ever!", 
              font=("Arial",10,"bold"),
              fg="red",
              bg="white",relief=RAISED,bd=10,
              padx=10,
              pady=10,image=Photo,
              compound="bottom")


Label.place(x=170,y=170) # -Placing the image in a specifed place 

Window.mainloop() # - Displays the window on the computer screen
```

However when using this code to create this a very simple GUI program it makes my icon in the corner of the window very pixelated compared to the icon in the taskbar.

How can I fix this?

My Image dimensions are 50 X 50 and the format of the file is png

Here is what my program looks like:

[image]

Here is what it looks like on the taskbar:

[image]

I have to fill in the part saying what I tried however except for trying to look up how to fix this I don't know what else to try myself.

Comment: The icon in the corner of your window is much smaller than the one that appears on your taskbar. Frankly it seems to have approximately the same level of detail as the text next to it, I don't know if you can reasonably expect much better quality, anyways have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71979301/resolution-of-the-image-in-the-top-left-of-a-window-in-tkinter as it seems to address basically the same issue.

Comment: I looked at that post and seen this statement which I think may be usefull, "You should be able to use tk.iconbitmap() with an .ico file if you want the full flexibility of the operating system choosing the best size. But if you want to specify a single file size, that’s also ok. For your case, you would need a 16x16 image though." However I don't know what to do with function because when using the function in this part of the code

Comment: `Icon = PhotoImage(file="AngryBird.png") 
Tk.iconbitmap(Icon)
Window.iconphoto(True,Icon)` I get this error : "AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_w'". What should I do with this function?

Comment: I believe you're supposed to pass the file path into `Tk.iconbitmap` not the image directly also https://pythonassets.com/posts/window-icon-in-tk-tkinter/ seems to be a good guide on customizing icons.

Comment: I will look at that later and try some things but for the meantime I can tell you that when using this code Icon = `PhotoImage(file="AngryBird.png") 
Tk.iconbitmap("AngryBird.png")
Window.iconphoto(True,Icon)` it gives me this error "'str' object has no attribute 'tk'"